# How to manipulate data when the website is in 3 languages?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I will develop a website using the bellows tools:

Joomla ,Mysql,wampserver  (I will code with PHP).

A user (according to the privileges) should choose the language then he can:

-Subscribe in our website (by filling a form name, last name, gender, profession, field of activity..)

-Search a list of the subscriber by choosing multiple criteria.

My question is :

The website will be in 3 languages, when some persons fill the form in English so the data stored will be in English and others in French also the data will stored in French.
How can I manipulate data with different languages?

Example:

For the research if a user (logged by choosing English languages) choose the gender for example “female”, so the result should be a list of all the persons subscribed, subscribed in English and in French.

How can I do that? Please I want help.

Answer (score 0):

the language you use to store data at the back-end is up to you. In your example, you could simply have a field named gender with the values m or f for male or female. The front-end website code will need to display it one of your 3 languages

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how Joomla in specific is handling multi-language sites, but, if you need to code something anew, then just use one constant and assign different kaywords to it.

```
+---------+--------+----------+-----------+
| cont_id | en     | fr       | sp        |
+---------+--------+----------+-----------+
| FEMALE  | Female | Féminin  | Femenino  |
| MALE    | Male   | Masculin | Masculino |
+---------+--------+----------+-----------+
```

This way you will be able to sort out exactly what you need, and in the language, the client has chosen.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, internationalized applications have everything coded in a single language - and with "coded" here, I do include web templates and messages that are presented to the user. These should  be specially marked so that they are recognized as translatable by your framework

The project them makes use of an internationalization framework, such as gettext - http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php - which allows the stripping of strings for translation into .pot files - these are the only things translators need to edit, and the translations are inserted back at run time.

You will have to figure out how your translation framework should work with your web page templates - maybe Joomla have something in place for that already.

As for your data, you have to keep all data "seem" by the program in a single lanaguie - typically in English (even for software developed in non native-English speaking parts of the World). What is presented to the user is the translated string - but the value stored on the database and compared by your application should all be in English- (it is for that  reason that  html tags such as `<option` have a "value" entry, separated from the tag content)